# Using a callback in implode()

Tags: php, closures

I have a multidimensional array, e.g.:

```
$values = array(
    'one' => array(
        'title' => 'Title One',
        'uri'   => 'http://example.com/one',
    ),
    'two' => array(
        'title' => 'Title Two',
        'uri'   => 'http://example.com/two',
    ),
);
```

...and I'd like to parse through that with a closure in my `implode` function, à la:

```
$final_string = implode(' | ', function($values) {
    $return = array();

    foreach($values as $value)
        $return[] = '<a href="' . $value['uri'] . '">' . $value['title'] . '</a>';

    return $return;
});
```

However, this usage yields an `Invalid arguments passed` error. Is there syntax that I'm missing which will make this use of [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) possible? I'm using PHP v5.3.16.

Comment: According to docs `implode` doesn't take a callback... Or am I missing something? If you just want to generate the array with a function and use it as parameter then you'd need to execute the function with `call_user_func`.

Comment: $return = array(); foreach($values as $value)
        $return[] = '<a href="' . $value['uri']...
$final_string = implode(' | ', $return);

Comment: Thanks @elclanrs - it's possible I'm misunderstanding closures, but I don't think so. The anonymous function I defined in the question _does_ return an array, satisfying the requirement for `implode`. Am _I_ missing something? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ashwin's answer is correct.  **Here's why:**

When you pass the closure directly to the `implode` method - which explicitly wants a second argument of type `array`, it essentially checks the `instanceof` - hence the invalid argument.  The `implode` function does not expect `mixed` and doesn't know to execute the closure.

When you first assign that function to a variable, it causes PHP to first evaluate that variable and it ends up passing the returned value from the function into `implode`.

In that case you're returning an array from the function and passing that into `implode` - that checks out.

**edit/adding**:  that anonymous function would be `instanceof Closure`.

```
Closure !== array
```

Comment: Lesson learned... thanks @kmfk. Simple proof of concept that you're totally right: `is_array(function() { return array(); });` returns `false`.

Comment: Side note, thank you for answering the actual **question** - not just giving _some_ solution :)

Answer (score 31):

Use `array_map`:

```
$final_string = implode(' | ', array_map(function($item) {
    return '<a href="' . $item['uri'] . '">' . $item['title'] . '</a>';
}, $values));
```

I trust you'll properly escape the values as HTML in your *real* code.

---

As to why this works and your code doesn't, you were passing a function as the second argument to `implode`. Frankly, that makes little sense: you can join a bunch of strings together, or maybe even a bunch of functions, but you can't join a single function together. It sounds strange, especially if you word it that way.

Instead, we first want to transform all of the items in an array using a function and pass the result of *that* into `implode`. This operation is most commonly called `map`. Luckily, PHP provides this function as, well, `array_map`. After we've transformed the items in the array, we can join the results.

Comment: Deleted my answer, this is just cleaner. No need for extra closure.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you need to assign the function to a variable, and then pass it through to make it work.

```
$fn = function($values) {
    $return = array();
    foreach($values as $value)
        $return[] = '<a href="' . $value['uri'] . '">' . $value['title'] . '</a>';
    return $return;
};
$final_string(' | ', $fn($values));
echo $final_string;
```

I am not sure what the reason is, though, and will need to check it in a little more depth to be able to give you a proper reason.

You can see the code working [here](http://3v4l.org/dklZo)

**EDIT** : Converted this answer to a community wiki so that everyone can contribute here.

**EDIT** : Explanation by @kmfk

When you pass the closure directly to the `implode` method - which explicitly wants a second argument of type `array`, it essentially checks the `instanceof` - hence the invalid argument. The `implode` function does not expect `mixed` type and doesn't know to execute the closure to get an `array`.

When you first assign that function to a variable, it causes PHP to first evaluate that variable and it ends up passing the returned value from the function into `implode`.

In that case you're returning an array from the function and passing that into `implode` - that checks out.

That anonymous function would be `instanceof Closure`, and

```
Closure !== array
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashwin Mukhija -- would love to know why we have to go through this extra step to accomplish _essentially_ the same thing.

Comment: Because you can't just chuck anything you like at native PHP functions. They must be used as designed and documented.

Comment: @kmfk You can put your explanation in this answer itself.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija - this is embarrassing - havent contributed to a community wiki answer yet.  would you just edit?

Comment: I meant, for future reference, would I just edit your answer?

Comment: It's a community wiki now, which means anyone can edit it, and it's useful for setting up collaborative answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use implode to what your trying to achieve, because implode only accept an `array` as the second argument.

You can try something like this.

```
$values = array(
    'one' => array(
        'title' => 'Title One',
        'uri'   => 'http://example.com/one',
    ),
    'two' => array(
        'title' => 'Title Two',
        'uri'   => 'http://example.com/two',
    ),
);

$links = array();
foreach ($values as $value) {
      $links[] = "<a href='" . $value['uri'] . "'>" . $value['title'] . "</a>";
}

$string = implode(" | ", $links);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function implode_callback( $array, $separator = '', $callback = false )
{
    return implode(
                    $separator,

                    $callback === false ?
                      $array : array_map( $callback, $array )
                  );
}
```

Example use:

```
$tab = array( 1, 2, 3 );

echo implode_callback( $tab, '<hr>', function($x) { return "<p>$x</p>"; } );
```

[See example code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa08c87e2fd2cde7bc5a54fd7d51052078a05bf9)