# Format date into an array with php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array;

```
Array
(
    [2017-04-01] => 0
    [2017-04-02] => 0
    [2017-04-03] => 0
    [2017-04-04] => 0
    [2017-04-05] => 0
)
```

How can I format the date to have something like this ?

```
Array
(
    [01-04-2017] => 0
    [02-04-2017] => 0
    [03-04-2017] => 0
    [04-04-2017] => 0
    [05-04-2017] => 0
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: this might be  similar to your question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311099/using-a-callback-in-implode

Comment: So you want the strings as key in a different format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `foreach` loop then covert to format `d-m-Y` can do this

```
$result = [];
foreach ($datas as $key => $value) {
    $date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($key));
    $result[$date] = $value;
}

print_r($result);
```